# Custom type converter doesn't appear to work in Filter

Tags: grails, gson

I am using the GSON type converter in a filter as follows...

```
def account = new Object(){
  String firstName, lastName
};

if(springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()){
  account.setFirstName(springSecurityService.principal.givenName);
  account.setLastName(springSecurityService.principal.familyName);
}
String test = account as GSON;
```

But test is always null, even thought the object is populated properly. I don't like all the extra data in the normal JSON serializer. So does anyone know why this does not work?

**UPDATE**

I get the following when converting to JSON...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor with modifiers "public"
```

Comment: Why create an object? Why not just a map? def test = [firstName: springSecurityService.principal.givenName, lastName: springSecurityService.principal.familyName] as GSON

Comment: What happens when I want to pass multiple accounts (unlikely in this exact scenario but still applicable for serializing objects in the filter). I also want it like that in this case because I would like to be able to access it as account.firstName in a JS app I am passing to and there is additional information.

Comment: Also in this case there is the possibility that I would want both principle and currentUser info and from my understanding they may be independent

Comment: You can build your map to contain other maps or a list of maps or list of maps of lists and so on as far as you need. [[key1: 'value', key2: 'value2'], [key1: 'value1a', key2: 'value2']] and so forth. As far as principal vs current user, I was just using that as an example. You can use whatever suits your needs.